# Nexus 5 not appearing in fastboot devices menu

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rom-flashing, fastboot, nexus-5, bootloader

I'm attempting to flash Android 4.4.4 KitKat onto my old Nexus 5, but when I run the `fastboot devices` command, it does not show my device's serial number. When I try doing the ADB sideload command though, it works. The "flash-all.bat" file doesn't work either as it says `<waiting for device>`. I am currently using platform-tools version 31.0.0.

Comment: Fastboot only works when you boot into bootloader mode. If adb sideload works you are most likely in recovey and not bootloader mode.

Comment: @Robert I am in bootloader mode. It still doesn't appear. The bootloader is also unlocked too.

Comment: Check device manager if the fastboot drivers are correctly installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Thought I already had the Google USB Drivers already installed but guess not.

Comment: drivers have to be installed separately for each boot mode